# Dropbox Desktop keeps uploading after closing

Tags: process, dropbox, cmd.exe, upload

I am using the Dropbox Desktop tool and upload (for my bandwidth) large amounts of data regularly. When I want to e.g. play online I just pause the upload. Since a few days when I pause it, it keeps using bandwidth even if I kill the process.

My resource monitor shows multiple Dropbox threads uploading data AFTER I killed the process using CMD:

```
taskkill /f /t /im Dropbox.exe
```

When I use the same command again the output says that no process with that name was found, but my resource monitor still shows this:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78029180/dropbox.png

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Have you waited an appropriate time (10-20 seconds) for updated information in Resource Monitor?

Comment: yeah I did. waited half an hour and the threads stayed active.

Comment: I see. That means the process wasn’t killed after all. Threads don’t exist without a parent process. Please take a look with [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653). Before killing the process, remember the process ID.